# Why does pixel art asset is looking over-compressed even if compression is disabled?

Tags: unity-game-engine, pixel

I have an 30x19 PNG asset. I want to show it in a SpriteRenderer but it looks like some kind of over-compressed. How can I fix that?

**This is what I see in the game screen:**

[image: Game Screen]

PS: Scale=2x in the screenshot. Nothing changes if I set it to Scale=1x

**This is the original asset:**
[image: The Original Asset]

**Here are the settings:**

- Project Settings -> Anti Aliasing: Disabled (Ultra - Very Low)
- Sprite Pixels Per Unit: 19
- Sprite Filter Mode: Point (no filter)
- Sprite Compression: None
- Camera Size: 5

**Sprite Settings:**
[image: Sprite Settings]

**Sprite Renderer Settings:**
[image: Sprite Renderer Settings]

**Camera Settings:**
[image: Camera Settings]

Where is the problem?

Comment: It doesn't look over-compressed to me, just black but that's because you selected its color to be black in the Sprite Renderer.

Comment: Can you please add this as an answer so I can accept it. :) Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look over-compressed to me, just black but that's because you selected its color to be black in the Sprite Renderer.

Turn that into white and your sprite should look like the original asset.